# Automatic rearrange two pdf files from a document "rectoverso"

Tags: batch-file, pdf, command, line

I have scanned a recto/verso file but my scanner is only recto so i have two pdf files.
The first one contains the pages 1-3-5-7-9 and the second one the pages 10-8-6-4-2 (in this order)

I would like to rearrange them in one pdf file with the pages in the good order.
But of course my real file contains more than 10 pages so it is a duty to do this.

Have you got an idea how to rearrange the both files in one correctly and automatically?

I thought a bash file with a command line software.
But which one (must be compatible on Windows 7)?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the easier portable way between the Linux and windows is performing a couple of tasks with the help of pdftk

1. first of all we take the second half of scans containing in decreasing order, the even pages

assuming, only for instance,  that our pdf (named **2half.pdf**) has 16 pages in this decreasing order:

**16 14 12 10 8 6 4 2**

while our first pdf has:

**1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15**

we type:

```
pdftk 2half.pdf cat end-1 output 2halfrectified.pdf
```

so, now our pdf has this page order:

**2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16**

finally, we need to merge these two pdf alternatively. To do this, we can use the recent feature implemented in pdftk since **1.44**

https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-shuffle

so to have this final page order merging these two pdfs

**1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16**

Comment: Here is an exemple to merge the two documents using shuffle: `pdftk half.pdf 2halfrectified.pdf shuffle output full.pdf`

Comment: `pdftk --help` has a oneliner example: `pdftk A=onefile.pdf B=otherfile.pdf shuffle A Bend-1 output collated.pdf`